# Excluding some taxonomy terms from a view when grouped by taxonomy

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

For node type 'people' I have tags A, B, C etc. Some people have multiple tags.

On my view I'm grouping them by taxonomy term and selecting A,B,C,D etc under 'Select terms from vocabulary People type' but I don't want to include E tag as a group on this page.

Nobody who is **only** E tag shows up, which is correct, and people who have E as one of their tags are there in their respective A,B,C tag groups, which is correct, **but** it also shows E tag as a group.

I don't want to specifically exclude E tag from my filter, as that gets rid of people tagged A,B,C.

How can I get E tag to stop showing as its own group?

Thank you!

Comment: If I remember correctly, grouping the results happens after the query returns the data and uses a field value to determine which group a row belongs. You can create add a field, and using its real/rewritten value, have it omit "E" when it sees it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes I have the SQL code set to visible and it doesn't group at that stage. Would you be able to elaborate on where to add the field, and how to omit it please? I already have people type in my Fields section so as to be able to group by them.